# Can anyone tell me what is the nature of design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

Can anyone tell me what is the nature of design patterns?
There are some patterns seem so simple and the others are too complex to understand, so what is the point?

Comment: A pattern is something that makes sense and therefore deserves being used again. Complexity is not relevant.

Comment: You learn patterns by yourself when you need them, no pattern is complex. And your question is too broad, also opinion based. Not good for StackOverflow type questions. Read the faq.

Comment: Some pattern solve specific problems (such as decorators, singleton and observers), since others give general guidance for architecture (mvc, mvvm, mvp. If you consider it as design pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are patterns that solves problems that are recurring in many projects. Those problems can be either simple or difficult, but the commonality of design patterns is that the solution can be reused in different domains but similar problems. Some problems are easier to 'solve' than others.

Answer (score 1):

> A design pattern in architecture and computer science is a formal way
>   of documenting a solution to a design problem in a particular field of
>   expertise

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Pattern)

> In software engineering, a design pattern is a general reusable
>   solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in
>   software design. A design pattern is not a finished design that can be
>   transformed directly into source or machine code.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

In my own words: design patterns give abstract descriptions of common problems and corresponding solutions related to (software) design.

Comment: I would also add that it started in Architecture with the book "A Pattern Language" (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_language) by Cristopher Alexander